# Remove one of multiple classes if it exists Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to check and remove a specific class of an element. I need it to be done using Javascript only, what I managed to find were mainly JQuery or non-working variants to me.

Here's my code:

```
 <ul>
   <li class = "tab"><a href="#">One</a></li>
   <li class = "tab"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
   <li class = "tab active"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
   <li class = "tab"><a href="#">Four</a></li>
 </ul>


 var NumThree = document.querySelector("li.tab active")

 function removeActiveClass(){
     if(NumThree !== null) {
         NumThree.classList.remove("active")
     }
 }
```

and [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1425m8kp/1/)

My code doesn't remove the class. So I am asking for **100% Javascript** help!

Comment: Where did `NumFour` come from?

Comment: Sorry for that - corrected

Comment: bunch of mistakes fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/bpm9o74u/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to correct selector into `document.querySelector("li.tab.active")` or just into `document.querySelector(".active")`and fire the function as `removeActiveClass()`. Like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1425m8kp/3/).

Answer (score 3):

Couple of Typos, **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1425m8kp/7/)** . The problem was in the way you were using the selectors, `document.querySelector("li.tab active")` will look for a element names `active` inside your `li` with the class `tab` (the space is used to search for a child element). what you actually wanted is a `li` with both the class `tab` and `active` so it should be `document.querySelector("li.tab.active")`

```
var NumThree = document.querySelector("li.tab.active")

function removeActiveClass(){    
    if(NumThree !== null) {
      NumThree.classList.remove("active");
    }
}

removeActiveClass();
```

Comment: `NumThree.className = "";` will remove the tab class too.

Comment: @Andy updated my answer, if you downvoted and if you feel now the answer is right, Can you please remove the downvote?

Comment: Why are you complicating it? The OP's code was better. Just use `remove`.

Comment: @Andy I just realized that.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers pretty much have this covered, you might think about how you could refactor the code so that the function is reusable.

Here, pass in the element and class as parameters to a more general function:

```
function removeClass(el, c) {
  if (el) el.classList.remove(c);
}

var NumThree = document.querySelector('li.tab.active')
removeClass(NumThree, 'active');
```